# Linq include() works on dev but not on azure

Tags: asp.net, linq, azure, include

I have a database schema as follows:

```
FailureItem
---------------
FailureID int foreign key references Failure (FailureID)
DatabaseID int NULL foreign key references Items (DatabaseID)
FailureDescription varchar(200)

Item
---------------
DatabaseID int primary key identity(1,1)
ItemDescription varchar(200)
```

I am using linq to bind this to a gridview as follows:

```
Dim items as List(Of FailureItems) =
    context.FailureItems.include("Item").where(function(x) x.FailureID = _failureID)



<asp:GridView ID="gv1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="databaseID" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FailureDescription" headertext="Failure Description" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Item.ItemDescription" headertext="Item Description" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This works perfectly on my development machine. When I release this onto azure, I get the error "A field or property with the name 'Item.ItemDescription' was not found on the selected data source." What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the right connection string is being used? Check in the properties pane for the role, make sure the Service Configuration setting is set to "Cloud" and verify that all the settings are correct.

Comment: I checked everything and it still didnt work - I even logged into the instance and checked the connection string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the code to the following, which worked:

```
Dim items =
    (from fi in context.FailureItems
     where(fi.FailureID = _failureID)
     select new with {
         fi.databaseID,
         fi.FailureDescription,
         ItemDescription = If(fi.Item isnot nothing, fi.Item.ItemDescription, nothing)
     }).ToList
```